# Append sections of string to list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a particularly long, nasty string that looks something like this:

```
nastyString = '  nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)\n  nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)\n  '
```

and so on. The key defining feature is that each "nameOfString" is followed by a `\n` with two spaces after it. The first nameOfString has two spaces in front of it as well.

I'm trying to create a list that would look something like this:

`niceList = [nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff), nameOfString2, Inc_(Stuff)]` and so on.

I've tried to use `newString = nastyString.split()` as well as `newString = nastyString.replace('\n  ', '')`, but ultimately, these solutions can't work because each nameOfString has a space after the comma and before the 'I' of Inc. Furthermore, not all the nameOfStrings have an 'Inc,' but most do have some sort of space in their name.

Would really appreciate some guidance or direction on how I could tackle this issue, thanks!

Comment: Maybe [`[x.split(', ') for x in s.strip().split('\n  ')]`](https://ideone.com/3fFWY0) will do?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew This seems to output many lists nested in one, giant list. However, I was hoping to have the output as:

`list=['nameOfString1, Inc(Stuff)', 'nameOfString2, Inc(Stuff)']` - any advice? Thanks for the input!

Comment: You already have lots of hints :)

Comment: Haha you are correct, I can figure this out now for sure, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nastyString = '  nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)\n  nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)\n  '
# replace '\n' with ','
nastyString = nastyString.replace('\n', ',')
# split at ',' and `strip()` all extra spaces
niceList = [v.strip() for v in nastyString.split(',') if v.strip()]
```

output:

```
niceList
['nameOfString1', 'Inc_(stuff)', 'nameOfString2', 'Inc_(stuff)']
```

Update: OP shared new input:

> That's awesome, never knew about the strip function. However, I actually am trying to including the "Inc" section, so I was hoping for output of: ['nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)', 'nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)'] and so on, any advice?

```
nastyString = '  nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)\n  nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)\n  '
niceList = [v.strip() for v in nastyString.split('\n') if v.strip()]
```

new output:

```
niceList
['nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)', 'nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)']
```

Comment: That's awesome, never knew about the strip function. However, I actually am trying to including the "Inc" section, so I was hoping for output of:

`['nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)', 'nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)']` and so on, any advice?

Comment: That's much easier. just not replace on `\n` and split on `\n`. I will update my answer

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try something like this.

```
 [word for word in nastyString.replace("\n", "").replace(",", "").strip().split(' ') if word !='']
```

Output:

```
['nameOfString1', 'Inc_(stuff)', 'nameOfString2', 'Inc_(stuff)']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

nastyString = '  nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)\n  nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)\n  '

new_string = [i for i in re.split("[\n\s,]", nastyString) if i]
```

Output:

```
['nameOfString1', 'Inc_(stuff)', 'nameOfString2', 'Inc_(stuff)']
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't like to replacing `'\n'` do this :

```
import re
nastyString = '  nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)\n  nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff)\n  '
word =re.findall(r'.',nastyString)
s=""
for i in word:
     s+=i
print s
```

> output :'nameOfString1, Inc_(stuff)  nameOfString2, Inc_(stuff) '

now you can use `split()`

```
print s.split(',')
```